# Use a @typeparam as component in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, blazor, type-parameter

Is it possible to use a `@typeparam` as Component?
More explicitly, do something like the following `MyComponent.razor`:

```
@typeparam TComponent

<TComponent />
```

Of course, there would also be a `MyComponent.razor.cs` file whose content would be:

```
public partial MyComponent<TComponent> : ComponentBase where TComponent : ComponentBase
```

so that the compiler would know that `<TComponent />` is meaningful.

I cannot find any documentation about this in Microsoft docs.

When I try it seems to compile, but display the following warning:

```
warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'TComponent'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace
```

However it is only a warning and not an error. It does't show anything in the browser though.

I am using ASP.NET 5.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is about using generics for Blazor content. Not sure if that's implemented yet. But did you see [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5282481/Microsoft-Blazor-Dynamic-Content) as a way for dynamic content? It's not the same, but maybe it can give you ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are trying to do but you can write what I believe you are trying to achieve as a component class like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;

namespace BlazorTest.Pages
{
    public class ComponentRenderer<TComponent> : ComponentBase where TComponent : IComponent
    {
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.OpenComponent<TComponent>(1);
            builder.CloseComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

So in Index.razor you can do something like the following to render a component of type `FetchData`:

```
....
<ComponentRenderer TComponent="FetchData"></ComponentRenderer>
....
```

If I'm wide of the mark post a little more information.

Comment: So basically, I was looking for a "native" way of doing that, but you provided me with a quick and pretty elegant way of doing it, so I'll give it a try and go with that if it works as expected, many thanks!